# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty }a^n$ if $|a|<1$ and $|a|>1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb R$. I want to prove that

**1)** If $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty }a^n=0$

**2)** If $|a|>1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty }|a|^n=+\infty $

Notice that I consider that excepted squeeze theorem or definition, I can't use other tools.

**My proofs**

**1)** If $a=0$ it's obvious. Suppose $a\neq 0$ and let $0<\varepsilon<1$. Then, if $N\geq \left\lfloor\frac{\ln \varepsilon}{\ln |a|}\right\rfloor+1$ we have that $|a^n|<\varepsilon$ if $n\geq N$ what prove the claim.

**2)** Let $M>1$. If we set $N=\left\lfloor \frac{\ln(M)}{\ln(|a|)}\right\rfloor+1$ we have that $|a|^n>M$ if $n\geq N$ what prove the claim.

**Are theses proofs correct ? If you have some other proof I would be happy to know them.**

Comment: could the downvoter explain ??

Comment: I don't believe your proofs are correct. Hint: Notice that if $|a|<1$ you can write $|a| = \frac{1}{1+b}$ for some $b>0$. Then $a^n = \frac{1}{(1+b)^n}$. Then use the binomial theorem.

Comment: For the second part, there is a theorem that says that $\lim s_n = +\infty$ iff $\lim \frac{1}{s_n} = 0$.

Comment: @joe15: What is wrong in these proofs ?? After reflexion, they look ok...

Comment: For example, for Part 1,  you have put a restriction on $\epsilon$. That is incorrect. The proof should read "Given any $\epsilon > 0$." That is directly from the definition. I realize you did that to get a positive N, but the definition says for ANY $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Similarly, the definition for divergence to $+\infty$ says that for any $M>0$. You have put a restriction on $M$ by saying "Let $M>1$."

Comment: @Joe: You don't look to really know what you are talking about... It's obvious that if $|a|\leq 1$ we have that $|a^n|\leq 1$ and thus, for $\varepsilon\geq 1$ we immediately have $|a^n|\leq \varepsilon$. Same for $M$, if it's ok for $M>1$ it's obvious that it works for $M>0$. Moreover, in the first definition we are interested at $\varepsilon$ very small and  in the second one in $M$ very big, therefore $\varepsilon>1$ and $M\leq 1$ are not interesting. In the same way; $\varepsilon>0.005$ or $M<3000$ are not interesting too if we can proov the definition for $\varepsilon<0.005$ and $M>3000$.

Comment: And it's moreover obivious that if it work for $\varepsilon<0.05$ then it work for $\varepsilon\geq 0.05$ and in the same way, if it work for $M>3000$ the it work if $M\leq 3000$, so you remark has no sense !!

Comment: Saying it's obvious does not make it a proof. You have to show that it is true for $\epsilon>0$. You have not done that except to say that it is obvious and that we are interested in $\epsilon$ being small (often true, but doesn't have to be). And your proof does fail if you don't restrict $\epsilon$ to be less than one. I'm done trying to help you. Take your proofs to your professor and see what they have to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.Another way is to use the binomial theorem. For abs(a)>1 let abs(a)=1+b where b>0. For positive integer n>1. the sum of the first two terms in the binomial expansion of $(1+b)^n$ is $1+bn$ and all of the other terms are positive. So if $y>n$ then $(1+b)^y>(1+b)^n>1+bn$.